# How to get heading value from location plugin from ios? Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, location

I'm using location plugin with Google maps for flutter. When I try to give rotation to custom marker, android works perfectly but ios always returns -1. I tried flutter_compass but i read this plugin does not work Huawei, Xiaomi. What Can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One way (probably not ideal) is to use `location` on Android and `flutter_compass` on iOS. You can perform a simple platform to see which one you're on:

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // use location
else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  // use flutter_compass
}
```

If the issues of `flutter_compass` with certain devices ever get patched, you can simply delete the check and use `flutter_compass` on both platforms.

Comment: this is actually a good idea. I'm gonna try it thanks :)